# Tkinter : Get font type of selected text

Tags: python, select, text, fonts, tkinter

I am making a text editor that when the user selects a part of the `Text` widget, the program will return the font type of it. Is there any way I can do this ? Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Your text widget will have a default font.  To be anything else, you will have to tag a slice of the text.  I believe you can get the tags of a char.  This http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html may help.

Comment: `print(textwidgetname['font'])` it prints font family name you mentioned while creating text widget,  if not default font name will be printed

Comment: But what if the user changed font of a part in that widget, and later select that part. How can I retrieve the font in that case

Comment: what do you expect to happen if the range of characters that is selected has more than one font?

Comment: I am expecting it to return the question mark (?)